# Hibernate missing column when dropping a column

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have a entity class like this:

```
@Entity
@Table (name="CART_ITEM")
public class CartItem {

@Id
@GeneratedValue (strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column (name="ID")
private int id;

@Column (name="AMOUNT")
private int amount;
...
```

It works fine with the database. But when I drop the column AMOUNT and remove the corresponding field above (with getters and setters) and restart the application, I get this:

```
 Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of    class com.retailstore.AppContextListener
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: manager] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
at   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:954)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:882)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
at com.retailstore.AppContextListener.createEntityManagerFactory(AppContextListener.java:76)
at com.retailstore.AppContextListener.contextInitialized(AppContextListener.java:66)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4842)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5303)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
at    org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
 Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing column [AMOUNT] in table [CART_ITEM]
at     org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.validateTable(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:85)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.doValidation(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:50)
at     org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:91)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:473)
at     org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
at     org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879)
... 14 more
```

I have done this many times before and have never encountered this problem. Does someone have any suggestions?

UPDATE:

I think the problem is solved. There where still old classes under WEB-INF/classes.

Comment: Hmm. Did you rebuild your project after removing the field?

Comment: Yep, rebuild, restarted eclipse, whatever restart there is..

Comment: If you find a solution, please consider in answering your own question, it may help others.

Answer (score 0):

I recognized that WEB-INF/classes contained old classes conflicting with this entity. I deleted those and the application worked.

Comment: That means that you did not build properly. Your eclipse build is either not configured to do web project or your change to the Java file was not made it eclipse.

Comment: Yes, not configured right sound reasonable. Can see the updated classes in a explorer window, but not in eclipse.